# intel_pstate driver not being loaded when added to grub file

Tags: drivers, grub2, cpu

I have a

```
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
Memory  16305MB (2531MB used)
Machine Type    Laptop
Operating System    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
```

In my **/etc/default/grub** file I have the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=enable"
```

I did a **sudo update-grub** after the changes but when I do a
**cpupower frequency-info or a cpufreq-info --driver** it says the driver used is **intel_cpufreq**

```
rt@sys76:~$ cpufreq-info --driver
intel_cpufreq


rt@sys76:~$ cpupower frequency-info

analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 20.0 us
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.70 GHz and 3.40 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 798 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
rt@sys76:~$
```

How can I get the **cpufreq-info --driver**
to use **intel_pstate** driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processor, i7-4700MQ, predates HWP (HardWare Pstate) control. The migration path as determined by the kernel power management group, for these Intel processors is to default towards the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver being in passive mode using the schedutil scaling governor. To that end this commit was done:

> commit 33aa46f252c703e42c81a76696cd0c240f2281e4 Author: Rafael J.
> Wysocki rafael.j.wysocki@intel.com Date:   Wed Mar 25 15:03:35 2020
> +0100
>
> ```
> cpufreq: intel_pstate: Use passive mode by default without HWP
>
> After recent changes allowing scale-invariant utilization to be
> used on x86, the schedutil governor on top of intel_pstate in the
> passive mode should be on par with (or better than) the active mode
> "powersave" algorithm of intel_pstate on systems in which
> hardware-managed P-states (HWP) are not used, so it should not be
> necessary to use the internal scaling algorithm in those cases.
>
> Accordingly, modify intel_pstate to start in the passive mode by
> default if the processor at hand does not support HWP of if the driver
> is requested to avoid using HWP through the kernel command line.
>
> Among other things, that will allow utilization clamps and the
> support for RT/DL tasks in the schedutil governor to be utilized on
> systems in which intel_pstate is used.
> ```

You are actually using the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, however it is in passive mode. Try this:

```
echo active | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
```

and then check:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
```

If that works as expected then change your grub line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=active"
```

and see if it boots the way you want.

Note that the CPU Frequency scaling driver `intel_cpufreq` is just the `intel_pstate` driver in passive mode.

Example:

```
doug@s19:~/temp$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_cpufreq

doug@s19:~/temp$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
passive
doug@s19:~/temp$ echo active | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
active

doug@s19:~/temp$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
```

Comment: Thanks, changing the grub file worked but it still boots up into "powersave" mode when checking the scaling.

Comment: @RickT : Yes, that is correct. If the intel_pstate scaling driver is "active" then "powersave" is the default governor. If the driver "passive" or the is the acpi-cpufreq  driver during boot, then the default governor will be "ondemand". Note that "active-powersave" is crudely the equivalent of "passive-ondemand". You can eliminate these default settings by stopping and disabling the "ondemand" service.

Answer (score 0):

The power supply for the laptop stopped working and I replaced it.  All of a sudden the cpu's started working properly again.  Looks like the power supply was going bad and not putting out enough current.